# Virtual keyboard events

Tags: javascript, jquery

Has anyone here encountered the problem that keyboard event is not triggered when it is virtual keyboard and key is not a number. This problem occurs with Nexus 7 tablet running on Android 6.0.1.

```
$('.some.selector').on('keypress', function () {
    console.log('Pressed');
})
```

Above code is fired when: key clicked is a number like 0-9, if using some other device like iPad or iPhone, or if i am remote debugging my tablet from pc then i can press physical keys from keyboard.
I am using Chrome 49 browser on my tablet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress

`keypress` event is deprecated and

> Chrome does not fire the keypress event for known keyboard shortcuts
>   (reference). Which keyboard shortcuts are known depends on the user's
>   system. Use the keydown event to implement keyboard shortcuts.

Try to use `input`, or `keydown/keyup' events instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup

Note!

> The DOM input event is fired synchronously when the value of an
>   < input> or < textarea> element is changed. Additionally, it fires on
>   contenteditable editors when its contents are changed. In this case,
>   the event target is the editing host element. If there are two or more
>   elements which have contenteditable as true, "editing host" is the
>   nearest ancestor element whose parent isn't editable. Similarly, it's
>   also fired on root element of designMode editors.

Comment: And how about those keypress events fired after pressing 0-9 keys ?

Comment: `keypress` is working, but it's deprecated. This means that in future it can not be supported, and better not to use it at all. Try other events, maybe thay will work to you.

Comment: Like u have said keydown event is triggered. However it always return keyCode 229.

Comment: look here - https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/3hr100/the_dreaded_keydown_keycode_of_229_for_android/ maybe this will help