# What's currently the best way to get onKeyUp events on Chrome in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

keyUp is not supported on Android Chrome due to using a virtual keyboard. `e.key` will always be `Undefined`, and `e.keyCode` will always be 229 no matter which key you use.

I want to know which key a user has done "keyUp" on last. What I have seen as proposed solutions are hacks, for example, if a user is using a textarea, just get the last character of the textarea target value. But these are not true solutions, if a user is editing the middle of a paragraph in a textarea, then this method will not work.

In modern Android Chrome browsers, what is the preferred way of getting a keyUp event?

Comment: @Yogi good catch I removed that link, the issue is still the same. keyUp event has no e.key or e.keyCode

Comment: @Yogi furthermore it is a long documented problem with many solutions that go back to 2012, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616567/how-to-listen-the-keypress-in-the-soft-keyboard . It's currently 2024 and I really disagree about closing this

Comment: One more comment: Android official documentation says: "never rely on receiving key events for any key on a soft input method (an on-screen keyboard)". But I can't accept this. There must be a way to get key events from a soft keyboard? The evidence is the wealth of Android apps that do this.

Comment: "wealth of Android apps that do this" doesn't mean that Android Chrome does this as those Java/Kotlin Android apps can be using their own Keyboard View or their own workarounds/hacks. Given that Chrome Android exists within the limits of Android OS I would check old/new [Chromium bugs](https://issues.chromium.org/issues?q=keyup%20android) for related issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtual keyboard events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862353/virtual-keyboard-events)